# creating a connection in eclipse - ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I am not doing anything in code - I just created an eclipse connection and can't seem to be able to ping it. The connection properties :

[image]

The jar is where I say it is ($GLASSFISH_HOME\domains\domain1\lib\ext) but I am getting :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:789)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.mysql.connection.JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That zip is very likely the distribution zip of MySQL Connector/J, inside of that zip is the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar` library with the driver. So you need to unzip it first and then add that `jar`-library instead of the zip.

Comment: Thanks I found out but I wonder should eclipse realize this on its own and warn me that there is no driver ? Do you think the situation qualifies for a bug report ?

Comment: It does warn you, that is what the `ClassNotFoundException` is for. And other than that, it is a rather hard problem to find out if there is a Driver in a library jar or zip you don't know (and on top of that you can add a lot more libraries (dependencies) for a driver that don't (and shouldn't) contain a Driver implementation.

Comment: Yes - but it accepts a zip (notice the Add jar/zip...) - mainly this was my issue...

Comment: That is because a `jar` is nothing more than a `zip` (and - afaik - in the early days it was not uncommon to have a library as a zip instead of a jar, not so common now though.